# Find sum of iterations of variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if ( i % 3 === 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
    if ( i % 5 === 0){
        console.log(i);
    }

}
```

I want to add each output of `i` together. `i.e. 0+0+3+5+6+9+10...+1000`

Is there an algorithm to do this, or do I just start adding every single one of these numbers together?

Comment: This is some elementary number theory.

Comment: Also please note that "elementary" isn't meant to be insulting; it's what that branch of maths is called :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sum of the numbers from 1 up to *n* is

```
n * (n + 1) / 2
```

The sum of the numbers from 1 up to 1000 that are divisible by 3 is the same as the sum of the numbers from one up to `1000 / 3`, multiplied by 3.  Similarly, the sum of the numbers from 1 to 1000 that are divisible by 5 is the same as the numbers from 1 to `1000 / 5`, multiplied by 5.

I bet the problem you're working on wants you to exclude numbers that are divisible by 15 :)

*edit* — Why does this work?  Well, consider the simpler case of the numbers from 1 to *n*; say, 1 to 100.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 97, 98, 99, 100
```

Now, consider that same list of numbers, but backwards:

```
100, 99, 98, 97, ... 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Note than when we add pairs from those two lists, we always get 101:

```
100 + 1 is 101
99 + 2 is 101
98 + 3 is 101
...
4 + 97 is 101
3 + 98 is 101
2 + 99 is 101
1 + 100 is 101
```

So there are 100 sums all the same, that being 101. If we do that multiplication and divide by 2, we've got the answer :)

Now, what about the sum of the numbers divisible by 3, or 5?  Well if you think about it, what do those numbers look like?

```
3, 6, 9, 12, ... 993, 996, 999
```

Hmm... that looks a lot like

```
3 * (1, 2, 3, 4, ... 331, 332, 333)
```

So the sum of the numbers 1 through 333 is `333 * 334 / 2`, and if we multiply that by 3 we get the sum of the numbers from 1 to 1000 that are divisible by 3. Same goes for 5.  If we want to drop the sum of the numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, we'd compute the sum of the numbers from 1 to `1000 / 15` and *subtract* that from the result.

Oh, and one more thing. If we're talking about a sum of integers, how do we know that that step where we divide by 2 won't leave us with a fraction? Well, the formula is `n * (n + 1) / 2`, remember. If `n` is an odd number, then `n + 1` is even. Thus, that multiplication will *always* involve one even number, so dividing by 2 will never leave us with a fraction!

Comment: Thanks Matt!  I fat-fingered that for sure :)

Comment: Can you prove why this works? It's not a terribly interesting answer when you don't show your work `:P`

Comment: +1 For the constant-time solution. I was sure one existed, but I couldn't quite get the 'sum of numbers up to *n* divisible by *m*' part.

Comment: I meant more "why does dividing by `(3|5)` work?" Sure, you can extend that same logic to say that there are 1/3 (or 1/5) the number of such pairs, but I'm not confident that handles all cases exactly. For example: what about numbers from 1 to 334?

Comment: @p.s.w.g it's a little tricky but if you consider the numbers from 1 up to 333, it kind-of makes sense.

Comment: @MattBall ah OK.  I'll keep going :)

Comment: @MattBall if you're only paying attention to numbers divisible by 3 in the range from 1 to 1000, then 334 doesn't matter.  Remember that this is all integer-domain stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a variable outside the loop to keep a running total:

```
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if ( i % 3 === 0){
        sum += i; // or sum = sum + i
    }
    if ( i % 5 === 0){
        sum += i; // or sum = sum + i
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks.Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: There is a constant-time solution :)

Comment: @user3041160 It hasn't been specified whether he wants that or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid counting multiple of 15 twice in your sum :

```
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
    if ( i % 3 === 0 ||  i % 5 === 0){
        sum += i; // or sum = sum + i
    }
}
```

Comment: Still a linear-time solution, which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Pointy : your thoughts have sent me back 2 decades ago! Many thanks for sharing!